# Number of different marks

Tags: algorithm

I came across an interesting problem and I can't solve it in a good complexity (better than O(qn)):

There are *n* persons in a row. Initially every person in this row has some value - lets say that *i-th* person has value *a_i*. These values are pairwise distinct.
Every person gets a mark. There are two conditions:

1. If *a_i* < *a_j* then *j-th* person cant get worse mark than *i-th* person.
2. If *i* < *j* then *j-th* person can't get worse mark than *i-th* person (this condition tells us that sequence of marks is non-decreasing sequence).

There are *q* operations. In every operation two person are swapped (they swap their values).
After each operation you have tell what is maximal number of diffrent marks that these *n* persons can get.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: We can deduce, that if i < j and a_i > a_j then i and j (and all inbetween) have to have the same mark, right?

Comment: In this problem *n < 500 000* so there can be even *500 000* diffrent marks (consider case where *a_i=i* ).

Comment: Yes, all of them have to have the same mark.

Comment: For example: n=8 , *a_i* sequence: 4 1 3 2 5 7 6 8. There are at most 4 marks(1 for [4 1 3 2] , 2 for [5] , 3 for [7 6] and 4 for [8]) and it satisfy conditions

Comment: To be clear: `q` operations are consecutive or parallel? In other words, do you need to update marks number after `q` accumulating changes or to analyze `q` possible swaps from the same starting position?

Comment: Consecutive. After each operation you get a new row(two values swapped comparing to previous) and next operations are performed on this new row.

Answer (score 1):

Consider any two groups, `J` and `I` (`j < i and a_j < a_i for all j and i`). In any swap scenario, `a_i` is the new max for `J` and `a_j` is the new min for `I`, and `J` gets extended to the right at least up to and including `i`.

Now if there was any group of `i`s to the right of `i` whos values were all greater than the values in the left segment of `I` up to `i`, this group would not have been part of `I`, but rather its own group or part of another group denoting a higher mark.

So this kind of swap would reduce the mark count by the count of groups between `J` and `I` and merge groups `J` up to `I`.

Now consider an in-group swap. The only time a mark would be added is if `a_i` and `a_j` (`j < i`), are the minimum and maximum respectively of two adjacent segments, leading to the group splitting into those two segments. Banana123 showed in a comment below that this condition is not sufficient (e.g., 3,6,4,5,1,2 => 3,1,4,5,6,2). We can address this by also checking before the switch that the second smallest `i` is greater than the second largest `j`.

Banana123 also showed in a comment below that more than one mark could be added in this instance, for example `6,2,3,4,5,1`. We can handle this by keeping in a segment tree a record of min,max and number of groups, which correspond with a count of sequential maxes.

**Example 1:**

```
                     (1,6,1)  // (min, max, group_count)
       (3,6,1)                      (1,4,1)

  (6,6,1)   (3,5,1)            (4,4,1)   (1,2,1)

6         5        3         4         2         1
```

Swap 2 and 5. Updates happen in log(n) along the intervals containing 2 and 5.
    To add group counts in a larger interval the left group's max must be lower than the right group's min. But if it's not, as in the second example, we must check one level down in the tree.

```
                      (1,6,1)
       (2,6,1)                       (1,5,1)

  (6,6,1)   (2,3,2)             (4,4,1)   (1,5,1)

6         2         3         4         5         1
```

Swap 1 and 6:

```
                      (1,6,6)
       (1,3,3)                       (4,6,3)

  (1,1,1)   (2,3,2)            (4,4,1)    (5,6,2)

1         2         3         4         5         6
```

**Example 2:**

```
                      (1,6,1)
       (3,6,1)                       (1,4,1)

  (6,6,1)   (3,5,1)             (4,4,1)   (1,2,1)

6         5         3         4         2         1
```

Swap 1 and 6. On the right side, we have two groups where the left group's max is greater than the right group's min, `(4,4,1) (2,6,2)`. To get an accurate mark count, we go down a level and move `2` into `4`'s group to arrive at a count of two marks. A similar examination is then done in the level before the top.

```
                      (1,6,3)
       (1,5,2)                       (2,6,2)

  (1,1,1)   (3,5,1)             (4,4,1)   (2,6,2)

1         5         3         4         2         6
```

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your solution but it seems to me that it doesnt work.
Consider this example:
n,2,3,...,n-2,n-1,1 and swap beetwen n and 1. How does your solution deal with this example?

Comment: @Banana123 `[6,2,3,4,5,1]` is exactly an example of two adjacent segments where `a_i and a_j (j < i)`, are the minimum and maximum of adjacent segments respectively. But you're right, in this case more than one mark is added. Let me consider that, it might just add a little elaboration to the basic idea.

Comment: And what about such case: n/2,n,...,1,n/2-1 with swap beetwen n and 1.

Comment: @Banana123 I addressed your `n/2,n,...,1,n/2-1` example in my answer. (working on the other example..)

Comment: @Banana123 I tried to address your second example, `n,2,3,...,n-2,n-1,1`, in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an *O*(*n* log *n*) solution:

- If *n* = 0 or *n* = 1, then there are *n* distinct marks.
- Otherwise, consider the two "halves" of the list, *LEFT* = [1, <sup>n</sup>/<sub>2</sub>] and *RIGHT* = [<sup>n</sup>/<sub>2</sub> + 1, *n*]. (If the list has an odd number of elements, the middle element can go in either half, it doesn't matter.)
- Find the greatest value in *LEFT* — call it *a*<sub>*LEFT_MAX*</sub> — and the least value in the second half — call it *a*<sub>*RIGHT_MIN*</sub>.
- If *a*<sub>*LEFT_MAX*</sub> < *a*<sub>*RIGHT_MIN*</sub>, then there's no need for any marks to overlap between the two, so you can just recurse into each half and return the sum of the two results.
- Otherwise, we know that there's some segment, extending at *least* from *LEFT_MAX* to *RIGHT_MIN*, where all elements have to have the same mark.
- To find the leftmost extent of this segment, we can scan leftward from *RIGHT_MIN* down to 1, keeping track of the minimum value we've seen so far and the position of the leftmost element we've found to be greater than some further-rightward value. (This can actually be optimized a bit more, but I don't think we can improve the algorithmic complexity by doing so, so I won't worry about that.) And, conversely to find the rightmost extent of the segment.
- Suppose the segment in question extends from *LEFTMOST* to *RIGHTMOST*. Then we just need to recursively compute the number of distinct marks in [1, *LEFTMOST*) and in (*RIGHTMOST*, *n*], and return the sum of the two results *plus 1*.

Comment: Result is required after each operation and using your method it would take  O(q*nlogn)

Comment: @Banana123: I see. Out of curiosity, I see that you've asked for a solution that's "better than O(qn)"; do you have any reason to think that such a solution exists?

Comment: This problem comes from Polish OI and constrains suggest that such solution exist

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get a complete solution, but here are a few ideas about what can and can't be done.

First: it's impossible to find the number of marks in O(log n) from the array alone - otherwise you could use your algorithm to check if the array is sorted faster than O(n), and that's clearly impossible.

*General idea*: spend O(n log n) to create any additional data which would let you to compute number of marks in O(log n) time and said data can be updated after a swap in O(log n) time. One possibly useful piece to include is the current number of marks (i.e. finding how number of marks changed may be easier than to compute what it is).
Since update time is O(log n), you can't afford to store anything mark-related (such as "the last person with the same mark") for each person - otherwise taking an array `1 2 3 ... n` and repeatedly swapping first and last element would require you to update this additional data for every element in the array.

*Geometric interpretation*: taking your sequence `4 1 3 2 5 7 6 8` as an example, we can draw points (i, a_i):

```
             |8
         +---+-
         |7  |
         |  6|
       +-+---+
       |5|
-------+-+
4      |
    3  |
      2|
  1    |
```

In other words, you need to cover all points by a maximal number of squares. Corollary: exchanging points from different squares `a` and `b` reduces total number of squares by `|a-b|`.

*Index squares approach*: let n = 2^k (otherwise you can add less than n fictional persons who will never participate in exchanges), let 0 <= a_i < n. We can create O(n log n) objects - "index squares" - which are "responsible" for points (i, a_i) : a*2^b <= i < (a+1)*2^b **or** a*2^b <= a_i < (a+1)*2^b (on our plane, this would look like a cross with center on the diagonal line a_i=i). Every swap affects only O(log n) index squares.
The problem is, I can't find what information to store for each index square so that it would allow to find number of marks fast enough? all I have is a feeling that such approach *may* be effective.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Let's *normalize* the problem first, so that *a_i is in the range of 0 to n-1* (can be achieved in O(n*logn) by sorting a, but just hast to be done once so we are fine).

```js
function normalize(a) {
    let b = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        b[i] = [i, a[i]];
    b.sort(function(x, y) {
        return x[1] < y[1] ? -1 : 1;
    });
    for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        a[b[i][0]] = i;
    return a;
}
```

To get the maximal number of marks we can count how many times

> `i + 1 == mex(a[0..i])` , `i` integer element [0, n-1]

`a[0..1]` denotes the sub-array of all the values from index `0` to `i`.

`mex()` is the *minimal exclusive*, which is the smallest value missing in the sequence 0, 1, 2, 3, ...

This allows us to solve a single instance of the problem (ignoring the swaps for the moment) in O(n), e.g. by using the following algorithm:

```js
// assuming values are normalized to be element [0,n-1]
function maxMarks(a) {
    let visited = new Array(a.length + 1);
    let smallestMissing = 0, marks = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        visited[a[i]] = true;
        if (a[i] == smallestMissing) {
            smallestMissing++;
            while (visited[smallestMissing])
                smallestMissing++;
            if (i + 1 == smallestMissing)
                marks++;
        }
    }
    return marks;
}
```

If we swap the values at indices x and y (x < y) then the mex for all values i < x and i > y doesn't change, although it is an optimization, unfortunately that doesn't improve complexity and it is still O(qn).

We can observe that the hits (where mark is increased) are always at the beginning of an increasing sequence and all matches within the same sequence have to be a[i] == i, except for the first one, but couldn't derive an algorithm from it yet:

```
0 6 2 3 4 5 1 7
*--|-------|*-*

3 0 2 1 4 6 5 7
-|---|*-*--|*-*
```